# Referenciar a PCL do xamarin com PCL's externas

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm

Ola pessoal surgiu uma duvida recentemente eu fiz um projeto em wpf usando padrão mvvm na qual fis em camadas. Agora quero reescrever o mesmo projeto com o xamarin, e reaproveitar o mesmo padrão, só que me deparei com a seguinte situação na qual o projeto pcl do xamarin não consigo referenciar a nenhum outro projeto apresentando o seguinte erro

```
Unable to add reference to project 'mvvm.ViewModel'. Portable Library projects can only reference other Portable Libarary projects and assemblies.
```

Então a pcl do xamarin não tem como referenciar a nenhum outro projeto pcl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso deve ocorrer por causa da compatibilidade (Targets) entre as PCL's.

Veja quais plataformas a PCL mvvm.ViewModel está referenciando. Os targets dessa PCL devem ser iguais ao da PCL que está recebendo a referência.

Comment: Participei da trilha Xamarin no TDC SP no ano passado. Legal ter alguém como você aqui no SO-pt, @AngeloBelchior ! Vai enriquecer bastante a comunidade. Seja muito bem-vindo! :-)

Comment: Obrigado. Eu não tenho costume de responder coisas no SO, caí aqui pesquisando outras  coisass e acabei dando uma olhada! Espero constribuir mais :) Valew

Comment: @AngeloBelchior também espero que responda bastante, o que precisar, estamos aí.

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Vou participar mais :)